# Strange SQLAlchemy behaviour when updating records

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I programmed a small blog system in Python, Flask and made a little template where i can edit posts with CKEdit. I have five posts:

```
A, B, C, D, E
```

If i want to update post A, once i made the edit, i actually get edited +3 posts, in this case, post D. All the original content of post D is overwritten by the edited content of A and the original content of A is untouched.

This happens in all posts except the last one. If i want to edit D, i get editted the post B, but i I edit E, the post is succesfully edited.

I think it's some issue with the database pointer, but dont know how to work on it.

The update code is this:

```
def set_post(title, text, timestamp, page):
    if page != '': #Update
        data = Post.query.get(page)
        data.title = title
        data.text = text
        db.session.commit()
[..]
```

I already checked the received "page" variable is correct (flash(page) just after the if sentence).

The underlying database engine is SQLLite 3.

Comment: Are you sure the page variable is actually the primary key? Can you show us the models, the rows, as well as what page is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `page` value is not the primary key. The `.get()` method query by primary key. To query by another column, use `filter_by()`. Example:

```
Post.query.filter_by(page=page).first()
```

Comment: Yep, was this. Thanks!